# i am trying to create a map using stamen toner that shows crime by location using marker clusters however it is not working

Tags: leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to produce a map showing a particular crime by location in juypter notebook using python.

```
crime_burg_01_18 = dfcrime_violence[['Latitude', "Longitude"]].values.tolist()

crime_map_01_18 = folium.Map(location=[54.903814, -1.747424], zoom_start=9, tiles='Stamen Toner')
MarkerCluster(locations = durham_burg_01_18, popups=dfcrime_violence['Crime type']).add_to(crime_map_01_18)
crime_map_01_18
```

error messages include syntax error or not in string

Comment: Some more details would help us help you. Can you cut and paste the first syntax error you're seeing?

Comment: There are a lot of details missing, how is for example durham_burg_01_18 defined?